# Is a randomly selected infinite subset countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The exercise (from Abbott's 'Understanding Analysis') required a proof that an infinite subset of a countably infinite set is countable. Abbott defined a function $g$ so that $g(1)$ equals the first term of the subset. He then says:  "Show how to inductively continue this process to produce a 1-1 function $g$ from **N** to A (the subset)". My problem was this: if the elements of A were randomly selected (from a countably infinite set B) how could any function work on consecutive elements of **N** to produce the elements of A? There must be a pretty basic misunderstanding of sets and subsets behind my difficulty. I have looked at all the questions on this topic but none address my problem. I would be very grateful to anyone who can help!

Comment: Here's an alternate approach: let $A\subset X$, where $X$ is a countably infinite set and $A$ is infinite. Since $A$ is infinite, there exists an injection $\mathbb N\to A$. Since $X$ is countable, there exists a bijection $X\to\mathbb N$. Composing that with the inclusion map $i:A\to X$, we get an injection $A\to\mathbb N$. Thus, by Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein, you are done.

Comment: Regarding the approach written here, I am very confused. 1. What is the "first term" of a set? Where do you invoke "random selection". Does Abbott actually do this? This just seems like a poor approach that obfuscates the point.

Comment: What do you mean by random? There is no uniform probability defined on a countably infinite set.

Comment: To emphasize also... functions don't need to be "nice" or "pretty" or have a discernable pattern.  The point is that we can know that such a function exists and if we were hard pressed to do so we could describe the first however many finitely many mappings given a specific $A$.

Comment: Note that since we were told that $B$ is countable... this implies the existence of such a bijective function $f~:~\Bbb N\to B$ which we can use in our definition for $g$... for example as $g(n)=x$ such that $x\in A$ and $\|\{x~:~f^{-1}(x)<f^{-1}(a)\}\|=n-1$... that is to say the $g(n)$ maps to the "$n$'th smallest element of $A$ according to the order induced by $f$."  The exact values contained in $A$ or $B$ don't really matter that much, regardless how chaotic they may seem.

Comment: I am pre-'injective' and 'bijective'. Abbott doesn't specify how to go about the proof by induction. But when I thought that, maybe A took a term of B then a dice was rolled and whatever number it landed the next term of A was that number of steps further into B, it would seem that no 'function' could be more than a definition, term by term, of A from B. Perhaps it's 'function' I don't understand? I'm happy with piecewise functions but this would be beyond piecewise.

Comment: Does the book actually use the phrase 'random', or does it use something like 'arbitrary'? The former seems like a dangerous conflation under the circumstances.

Comment: Dang @StevenStadnicki said what I was going to say: random and arbitrary are distinct things in mathematics. Colloquially, they're used interchangeably, but random has with it extra baggage related to probability (i.e. measure theory), whereas arbitrary does not.

Comment: @JMoravitz Your comment sounds like the answer I was looking for. I do not know what the two upright parallel lines stand for and please could you expand a little on what stands between them? Especially what $<f^{-1}(a)$ means. What is this 'a'